# Play Video from URL in Android

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

As a part of a research I'm looking for of the options to play video from an applications (As an application developer)

I know of 2 options:

1. MediaPlayer Object which can play video from url or local video
2. VideoView Object which is a wrapper for MediaPlayer and also can play video from both url and local video.

Are there another options of placing "Video" Object in an application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google ExoPlayer (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) which is in development but work very well.

> Playing videos and music is a popular activity on Android devices. The
>   Android framework provides MediaPlayer as a quick solution for playing
>   media with minimal code, and the MediaCodec and MediaExtractor classes
>   are provided for building custom media players. The open source
>   project, **ExoPlayer, is a solution between these two options, providing
>   a pre-built player that you can extend.**

Comment: Thanks! What do I need to do in order to override the MediaPlayer of Android?

Comment: ExoPlayer is not an Override of MediaPlayer. According to the documentation : `ExoPlayer is a media player built on top of the MediaExtractor and MediaCodec` So you do not Override the MediaPlayer but import the library project into your IDE

Comment: Yes I know, I asked in a different context - If I want to override MediaPlayer, how do I do that? Thanks again :)

Comment: never tried but you can surely create your
`public class CustomMediaPlayer extend MediaPlayer`